# How do I draw a watermark onto an image?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

How do I draw a watermark onto an image I have searched online and have even searched for JavaScript imaging libraries but haven't found anything that would allow me to do this. How can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript to do so. There is a JS library that makes this task easier called [watermark.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/).